# Need a hassle-free backup solution for Windows -- needs to be bootable

Tags: windows-vista, backup

I run Windows Vista.

I am looking for a relatively painless way to backup my main system disk (lets assume C: ) to an USB-mounted drive.

- The USB mounted drive has the same disk geometry as my main C: disk
- backup needs to happen automatically (i.e. through scheduled tasks) on a schedule
- If and when my main disk has a hardware failure, I should just be able to

  - take out the faulty drive
  - and replace it with the USB mounted drive
  - and should be able to boot my Windows system as if nothing bad has happened.

Jamie Zawinski describes the my ideal system [here](http://www.jwz.org/doc/backups.html) (Look at "Option 2"), but his scheme only works on Macs.

I have seen several questions and answers on this site regarding topics that are similar, but havent quite found a topic that directly addresses my question...

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are wanting to do to clone your drive to a USB drive.  Here is some software that i found that might be useful to you:

> 1. **[Macrium Reflect Free:](http://www.macrium.com/ReflectFree.asp)** (Open Source Software)
>
> *This software is able to image your currently running system (using a facility known as Microsoft Volume Shadow copy Service) to another local hard disk, to the Network, a USB or Firewire drive, and DVD. It has a built-in scheduler, so that you can schedule it to back up your system at a convenient time by itself, has 32 bit and 64 bit versions, comes with a Linux-based bootable rescue CD as well as a BartPE plugin, etc. (The commercial full version includes the ability to automatically verify images made, password protection of your images, a Windows PE 2.0 rescue CD with RAID support, etc.)*
>
> 2, **[Norton Ghost 15](http://www.symantec.com/norton/ghost)** (Paid Software)
>
> - **Creates full system and file backups** 
>     — Safeguards your system, settings, applications, and files with flexible, comprehensive backup protection.
> - **Restores from system failures** 
>     — Recovers your system and data even when you can’t restart your computer.
> - **Enables convenient, secure offsite backups** 
>     — Saves recovery points to an FTP site for easier offsite management and even backs up 
>     your data to network-attached storage devices.
> - **Backs up on schedules and events** 
>     — Lets you decide what is backed up and when so you can customize backups based on how you use your computer.

Comment: i've used macrium reflect free and it works quite well (use the alternate restore disk though). Paid solutionwise, acronis is supposed to be decent as well.